# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'AUTHORBOOKDB.AUTHOR'

Tags: java, derby

I'm working with a local derby server and I'm having issues with an error saying java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'AUTHORBOOKDB.AUTHOR'.
I have my database set up and and ID is showing in the schema AUTHORBOOK.AUTHOR.

Here are my two entities:

```
AuthorDAO.java

package entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import core.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class AuthorDAO implements DAO<Author>
{   
    public AuthorDAO() {

    }
    List<Author> authors;

    /**
     * Get a single author entity as a author object
     * @param id
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<Author> get(int id) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Author WHERE ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            Author author = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                author = new Author(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"), rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
            }
            return Optional.ofNullable(author);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all author entities as a List
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public List<Author> getAll() {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        authors = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Author";
            rs = db.executeQuery(sql);
            Author author = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                author = new Author(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"), rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
                authors.add(author);
            }
            return authors;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert a author object into author table
     * @param author
     */
    @Override
    public void insert(Author author)
    {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Author(ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, author.getID());
            stmt.setString(2, author.getFirstName());
            stmt.setString(3, author.getLastName());
            int rowInserted = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowInserted > 0) {
                System.out.println("A new author was inserted successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update a author entity in database if it exists using a author object
     * @param author
     */
    @Override
    public void update(Author author) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE Author SET FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=? WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, author.getFirstName());
            stmt.setString(2, author.getLastName());
            stmt.setInt(4, author.getID());
            int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsUpdated > 0) {
                System.out.println("An existing author was updated successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a author from author table if the entity exists
     * @param author
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Author author) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM Author WHERE ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, author.getID());
            int rowsDeleted = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
                System.out.println("A author was deleted successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all column names in a list array
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Author WHERE ID = -1";//We just need this sql query to get the column headers
            rs = db.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            //Get number of columns in the result set
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberCols; i++) {
                headers.add(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));//Add column headers to the list
            }
            return headers;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        } 
    }
}




BookDAO.java 

    package entity;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import core.*;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;


public class BookDAO implements DAO<Book>
{
    public BookDAO() {

    }
    List<Book> books;

    /**
     * Get a single book entity as a book object
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<Book> get(int id) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            Book book = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                book = new Book(rs.getInt("ISBN"), rs.getString("TITLE"), rs.getInt("AUTHORID"));
            }
            return Optional.ofNullable(book);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all book entities as a List
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public List<Book> getAll() {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        books = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Book";
            rs = db.executeQuery(sql);
            Book book = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                book = new Book(rs.getInt("ISBN"), rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"), rs.getInt("AUTHORID"));
                books.add(book);
            }
            return books;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert a book object into book table
     * @param book
     */
    @Override
    public void insert(Book book)
    {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Book(ISBN, title, authorid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, book.getIsbn());
            stmt.setString(2, book.getTitle());
            stmt.setInt(3, book.getauthorID());
            int rowInserted = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowInserted > 0) {
                System.out.println("A new book was inserted successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update a book entity in database if it exists using a book object
     * @param book
     */
    @Override
    public void update(Book book) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE Book SET ISBN=?, TITLE=?, WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, book.getIsbn());
            stmt.setString(2, book.getTitle());
            stmt.setInt(4, book.getauthorID());
            int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsUpdated > 0) {
                System.out.println("An existing book was updated successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a book from book table if the entity exists
     * @param book
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Book book) {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, book.getIsbn());
            int rowsDeleted = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
                System.out.println("A book was deleted successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all column names in a list array
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        DB db = DB.getInstance();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE ID = -1";//We just need this sql query to get the column headers
            rs = db.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            //Get number of columns in the result set
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberCols; i++) {
                headers.add(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));//Add column headers to the list
            }
            return headers;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also here's the stacktrace:

```
INFO: Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory createDbSupport
INFO: Database: jdbc:derby:authorbookdb (Apache Derby 10.10)
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl removeFailedMigrations
INFO: Repair of failed migration in metadata table "AUTHORBOOKDB"."schema_version" not necessary. No failed migration detected.
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbRepair repair
INFO: Metadata table "AUTHORBOOKDB"."schema_version" successfully repaired (execution time 00:00.230s).
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate validate
INFO: Validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.007s)
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate migrate
INFO: Current version of schema "AUTHORBOOKDB": 1
Apr 06, 2020 8:13:05 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate logSummary
INFO: Schema "AUTHORBOOKDB" is up to date. No migration necessary.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'ID' is not a column in table or VTI 'AUTHORBOOKDB.AUTHOR'.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There error is that there is no ID in AUTHORBOOKDB.AUTHOR', but you talk about AUTHORBOOK.AUTHOR. Where is DB defined in your code? And where is the connection to the database made? I suspect it is a simple typo somewhere.

Comment: I have my db url defined in a DB class as defined `private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:authorbookdb;create=true;user=authorbookdb;password=password";` and I use flyway to initialize the db @NomadMaker

Comment: Yes, you stated that you checked the authorbook database. I suspect that you shouldn't be using authorbookDB in the jdbc connection string.

Comment: @NomadMaker that was the problem I changes it. Thanks!